# Injecting an Enumerable containing all registered Implementations of an Interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Given the following interface:

```
public interface IMyProcessor
{
    void Process();
}
```

I'd like to be able to register multiple implementations and have my DI container inject an enumerable of them into a class like this:

```
public class MyProcessorLibrary
{
    private readonly IMyProcessor[] _processors;

    public MyProcessingThing(IMyProcessor[] processors)
    {
        this._processors = processors;
    }

    public void ProcessAll()
    {
        foreach (var processor in this._processors)
        {
            processor.Process();
        }
    }
 }
```

Is this possible? My current implementation of `MyProcessorLibrary` looks up all the `IMyProcessor` implementations statically, but I'd rather do it through a container if I can. I'm using Unity, but am curious if other containers support it.

**Edit:**

Thanks for the answers so far; to be clear I want to inject `MyProcessorLibrary` into another class, and have it built as part of the wiring up of a tree of dependent objects, e.g.

```
public class MyProcessorRepository
{
    public MyProcessorRepository(MyProcessorLibrary processorLibrary)
    {
    }
}

public class MyProcessorService
{
    public MyProcessorService(MyProcessorRepository processorRepository)
    {
    }
}

var container = new UnityContainer();
// Register a bunch of IMyProcessors...

var service = container.Resolve<MyProcessorService>();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving IEnumerable<T> with Unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961549/resolving-ienumerablet-with-unity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak for Unity as I don't use it but it is definitely possible with [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) (see  [Multi Injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection)) which I do use.

Comment: Awesome, that's actually exactly what I want to do... if nothing turns up for Unity I'll accept this answer in a bit. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to do this. All you need, is to give *string names* to the types you are registering with the interface. `Register` without a string name still assignes a name (as far as I remember it is *"Default"*) internally, it is resolved when you call `Resolve<T>`, **but** it is not resolved when you call `ResolveAll<T>`. So you may need to give all your processors some names.

A sample from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660852%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) (adapted):

```
// Create container and register types using a name for each one
IUnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyProcessor, MyProcessorA>(); //default
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyProcessor, MyProcessorB>("MyProcessorB");
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyProcessor, MyProcessorC>("MyProcessorC");

// Retrieve a list of non-default types registered for IMyProcessor
// List will only contain the types MyProcessorB and MyProcessorC
IEnumerable<IMyProcessor> serviceList = myContainer.ResolveAll<IMyProcessor>();

//usage
var library = new  MyProcessorLibrary(serviceList);
library.ProcessAll();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I don't think I was quite clear enough in my question. I've updated it.

Answer (score 2):

This is from Microsoft Unity 2.0  documentation. Check out the version you use. Not sure for others IoC.

```
// Create container and register types using a name for each one
IUnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyProcessor, MyProcessor1>();
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyProcessor, MyProcessor2>("number2");

// Retrieve a list of non-default types registered for IMyService
IEnumerable<IMyProcessor> processors = myContainer.ResolveAll<IMyService>();
```

**EDIT:**

```
// update MyProcessorLibrary with this property
[Dependency]
public IEnumerable<IMyProcessor> MyProcessingThing
{
 get { return _processors; }
 set { _processors = value; }
}

 //then inject the library class like this
 var lib = myContainer.Resolve<MyProcessorLibrary>();
 myProcessorRepository(lib)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I don't think I was quite clear enough in my question. I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

It is fully supported with MEF.

You'd have to Export all the classes that implement this interface, then use [ImportMany]

Example:

```
public interface IMyProcessor { void Process(); }

[Export(typeof(IMyProcessor)]
public class FirstProc : IMyProcessor { ... }

[Export(typeof(IMyProcessor)]
public class SecondProc : IMyProcessor { ... }

[Export]
public class MyTest()
{
   [ImportMany]
   public IMyProcessor[] MyProcessors { get; set; }
}
```