# How to inject the correct concrete class into a closed sytstem

Tags: c#, hangfire, hangfire-unity

`Hangfire` looks to be pretty slick.  However, I am having a challenge getting `Hangfire` to activate the correct concrete class.

Some background:

```
public interface IJob
{
    bool Execute(string payload);
}
public interface IJobPayload
{
    string UserId { get; set; }
    string JobName { get; set; }
    string JobQueueName { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    JobType JobType { get; set; }
    CronExpression Cron { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have (potentially) hundreds of Jobs that **all** inherit from `IJob` and execute on a payload that inherits from `IJobPayload`.  Without getting into depth on each of the Job's Execution code, I have something like:

```
[Queue("critical")] class Job1 : IJob {...}
[Queue("doors")] class Job2 : IJob {...}
[Queue("doors")] class Job3 : IJob {...}
[Queue("lights")] class Job4 : IJob {...}
[Queue("lights")] class Job5 : IJob {...}
[Queue("adhoc")] class Job6 : IJob {...}
...
[Queue("critical")] class JobN : IJob {...}
```

To provide a sample of a basic Job:

```
public class JobDoorStatusChanged : IJob
{
    [Queue("doors")]
    public bool Execute(string payload)
    {
        var command = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payload>(payload);
        // handle execution here...
        return true/false;
    }

    public class Payload : IJobPayload
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public string JobQueueName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public JobType JobType { get; set; }
        public CronExpression Cron { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a Web API Post controller that is very simple:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post()
{
    var payload = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var queueHandler = new QueueHandler();
    return queueHandler.Load(payload);
}
```

And the next step is where I am meeting failure.  He and I are getting to be best buds.  Unfortunately!

Hangfire has 4 Enqueue methods (2 sync, 2 async):

```
public static string Enqueue([NotNull, InstantHandle] Expression<Action> methodCall)
public static string Enqueue([NotNull, InstantHandle] Expression<Func<Task>> methodCall)
public static string Enqueue<T>([NotNull, InstantHandle] Expression<Action<T>> methodCall)
public static string Enqueue<T>([NotNull, InstantHandle] Expression<Func<T, Task>> methodCall)
```

They either take a static class:

```
var id = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyStaticJob.Execute(payload));
```

Or they take a type that should be resolvable from Unity:

```
var id = BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ConcreteJobDefinition>(a => a.Execute(payload));
```

Since I have dozens, scores even way too many objects which **are all based on IJob** neither of these entry points are working for me.

I even went so far as to try a single class to wrap all my jobs and have Hangfire execute the single class and so far, no luck:

```
public interface IJobService
{
    bool Execute(string payload);
}
public class JobService : IJobService
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
    public bool Execute(string payload)
    {
        var command = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayloadStub>(payload);
        var job = _container.Resolve<IJob>(command.JobName);
        return job.Execute(payload);
    }
    internal class PayloadStub : IJobPayload
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public string JobQueueName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public JobType JobType { get; set; }
        public CronExpression Cron { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I can execute a single concrete implementation this way (talk about obfuscation!):

```
var id = BackgroundJob.Enqueue<JobService>(a => a.Execute(payload));
```

Still nothing!  **And**, you lose the `Queue Attribute` from every single job!

So, I went back to my `startup.cs` file:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        Framework.Initialize(); // internal framework here at work...
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        UnityConfig.RegisterUnity();           // <== UNITY ==
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        HangfireConfig.RegisterHangfire(app);  // <== HANGFIRE ==
    }
}
```

Class UnityConfig:

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterUnity()
    {
        var container = Sol3.Web.WebApi.App_Start.UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

        // Register Auth & Exception handlers...
        container.RegisterType<IAccessDeniedResult, AccessDeniedResult>();
        container.RegisterType<IExceptionResult, ExceptionResult>();
        container.RegisterType<IJobService, JobService>();

        // Register all IJob concrete implementations found in this project...
        container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(type => typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsClass),
            WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
            t => t.IsNested ? t.DeclaringType.Name + "." + t.Name : t.Name,
            WithLifetime.Transient);
    }
}
```

Class HangfireConfig:

```
public class HangfireConfig
{
    public static void RegisterHangfire(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(Globals.DatabaseHangfire);
        GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new LogAttribute());
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
        {
            Queues = Globals.QueueNames,
            Activator = new UnityJobActivator(Sol3.Web.WebApi.App_Start.UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer()),
        };
        app.UseHangfireServer(options);

    }
}
```

I don't see anything wrong there.  Unity has all the registrations.  Since I have so many objects based on a single interface I know I am breaking how Unity is usually used for Dependency Injection.

Any thoughts?  Any tweaks to code that you can see?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the developer found a bug and has fixed it.  I am testing it out now and so far it looks more pronising than not.

[Hangfire Issue #656](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/656)

I also found an error with my definition.  I needed to change my **Execute** from a *bool* to a *void* return type.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and worked around it using a generic wrapper called `JobHandler<T>` that enqueues the job. It works like this:

First, a base `JobHandler`:

```
public abstract class JobHandler
{
    public abstract void Enqueue(string payload);
}
```

Next, `JobHandler<T>` which will handle enqueuing with Hangfire as the correct concrete type:

```
public abstract class JobHandler<T> : JobHandler 
    where T: IJob
{
    public override void Enqueue(string payload)
    {
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue<T>(x => x.Execute(payload));
    }
}
```

`JobHandler<T>` doesn't necessarily need to be abstract, but in my case I have additional logic performed by the handler and provide a concrete implementation of it for each job type. The handler for each type is then registered with my application and I can simply do:

```
JobHandler handler = Activator.CreateInstance(GetHandler("MyJobType")) as JobHandler;

handler.Enqueue(payload)
```

Should be easy enough to do the same using Unity to resolve the `JobHandler` instead. That said, I'm not sure this provides much benefit over simply resolving the `IJob` and queuing the instance now that the bug that was causing your problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

While the core concept is slightly different, and there might be a cleaner way to do it, you might try registering the Jobs as an IEnumerable then pick which one you need based on name. I had a related issue in which I wanted to process N handlers for an implementation based on criteria passed in. I did a write up on it [in my blog](http://www.whoiskevinrich.com/using-dependency-injection-for-implementation-enumeration).

There is a Unity example in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599634/2449105)