# c# Unity container constructor injection of list<childs>

Tags: c#, unity-container

I would like to know how can we inject List of all child objects of an abstract class to a constructor using xml config.

E.g.:

```
Class Test
{
 public Test(List<A> instances) // So this list should have instance of B & C
{

}
}

abstract Class A
{

}

Class B: A
{

}

Class C: A
{

}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you mean B and C inherit A?

Comment: oops!!! corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following config if you change a type of a `Test`'s constructor argument on `IList<A>`:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <namespace name="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <namespace name="ConsoleApplication1" />
    <assembly name="ConsoleApplication1" />
    <container>
      <register type="A" mapTo="B" name="B" />
      <register type="A" mapTo="C" name="C" />
      <register type="IList`1[[A]]" mapTo="A[]" />
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

So the trick is to map `IList<A>` interface on `A[]` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1961549/2858407) for details.

Comment: Thanks Stop-cran.  How do I resolve this now so that  Test constructor gets the list<A> with B & C  in it?

Comment: I am able to resolve it now and it's being passed correctly as List<A> with B & C instance.  Thanks stop-cran.